'rechts oder links' or 'links oder rechts'
The two sentences

Ist das Museum rechts oder links?

and

Ist das Museum links oder rechts?

are practically the same.
I wonder if the two phrases 'rechts oder links' and 'links oder rechts' are equally frequently used. Otherwise, is the one more common to native German speakers?

Perhaps this Ngram chart can answer the question.

I think this question can't be answered: if any difference in usage exists, then this would more likely be in spoken language and exactly this is not covered by tools like Google ngram.

To quote Ernst Jandl: "lechts und rinks / kann man nicht / velwechsern. / werch ein illtum!"

It would be nice to mention what motivated that question. Is there a notable difference in another language you know? Is there a difference between any words combined with "or" in any language you know?

The version »rechts oder links« was used about 7 times as often as »links oder rechts« in documents printed in 1806 and later scanned by Google. This ratio decreased over the next 200 years, and in documents printed in 2006 (and later scanned by Google), both versions were used with exactly the same frequency. Then »links oder rechts« was used a few percent more often than »rechts oder links« and in documents printed in 2022 again both versions were used with exactly the same frequency. More recent data is not currently available.
These facts are shown in this Google Ngram:

Source: Google Ngram

In my spontaneous speech I'd probably use "links oder rechts", but don't ask why. Perhaps the reason is that our style of writing is left-to-right. [It was once pointed out in a text by Ephraim Kishon that Hebrew is the language of a culture based on texts: If people carved texts into stone already two thousand years ago, based on the experience by any right-handed man using hammer+chisel to get a result, it were evident that one would write right-to-left...]
